# Javascript framework for video recording and editor

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, javascript-framework

Which javascript framework that recommended if i want to make video recording function and video editor (modify video playback speed) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this question does not fit the requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please only ask questions with a specific problem

Comment: Questions to recommend software tools are of-toppic while still in the categories of stackoverflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic